# how to import csv file into table of sql server other than BUIK INSERT

Tags: sql, csv, import

I googled the solution online and most of the result comes back with BULK INSERT, I don't have the access to this role at this point so this is not an option.

Is there any other generic way to import .csv file into MS SQL SERVER?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I end up doing is go to task--->import, this is the original DTS functionality and it does give me option to import excel file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use either SSIS or bcp if you don't have bulk insert rights. Although I would be open to learning another way.

Answer (score 0):

Solution I've done the last few times I've needed to do this was save the CSVs as .XLS in excel and then pull it in from SSMS.

Edit: [Here's a SO answer that shows how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474137/how-to-export-data-from-excel-spreadsheet-to-sql-server-2008-table)