# Insert multiple rows into multiple table without repeating "INSERT INTO"

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I was given a set of data in EXCEL (600+ rows) that I need to insert into 3 different tables (Membership, Account, Participant). The data look something like this:

```
ID    FirstName    LastName    DOB        Account_Type  Status    Participant_Code    Participant_Type
1     John         Smith       5/5/1960   Gold          Active    002                 A
2     Hello        World       4/9/1975   Platinum      Inactive  002                 A
.
.
.
600
```

I need to:

```
INSERT INTO Membership (ID, FirstName, LastName, DOB)
VALUES (1, 'John', 'Smith', '5/5/1960')

INSERT INTO Membership (ID, FirstName, LastName, DOB)
VALUES (2, 'Hello", 'World", '4/9/1975')

INSERT INTO Account(ID, Type, Effective_Date, Status)
VALUES (1, 'Gold', GetDate(), 'Active')

INSERT INTO Account(ID, Type, Effective_Date, Status)
VALUES (2, 'Platinum', GetDate(), 'Inactive')

INSERT INTO Participant(ID, Code, Type)
VALUES (1, 002, 'A')

INSERT INTO Participant(ID, Code, Type)
VALUES (2, 002, 'A')
```

I do not want to repeat 600 * 3 `INSERT` statement. What are my options?

Edit: Sorry, forgot to mention - Bulk insert is not an option due to the limitation on my work station.

> > Update:
> >     Donal provided me with a good starting point. Even though I still need 600+ INSERT statements, with the help from Donal, at least I don't have to write the statement myself. Also, I have modified my code to make it more efficient:

First, I `CREATE and INSERT` these 600 rows into a temp table.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp_table (
ID               INT,
FirstName        VARCHAR(50),
LastName         VARCHAR(50),
DOB              DATE,
Account_Type     VARCHAR(10),
Status           VARCHAR(8),
Participant_Code CHAR(3),
Participant_Type CHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO #temp_table (1, 'John', 'Smith, '5/5/1960', 'Gold', 'Active', '002', 'A')
.
.
so on
```

Then, for the specific table, I can just use the `INSERT INTO... SELECT` statement

```
INSERT INTO Membership
SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, DOB FROM #temp_table

INSERT INTO Account
SELECT ID, Account_Type, Status, GetDate() FROM #temp_table

INSERT INTO Participant
SELECT ID, Participant_Code, participant_type FROM #temp_table
```

Comment: are you familiar with bulk insert wizard from SSMS?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452859/inserting-multiple-rows-in-a-single-sql-query

Comment: @xQbert I have done my research before posting my question here. The link you showed me only reduces the `VALUES` keyword, but I still need to enter the data 600 * 3 times

Comment: It reduces the `Insert into tableName (field names) values`.  the data still has to be listed; else how would it be inserted...

Comment: @xQbert Just found out your method doesn't work in SQL Server 2000 either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Excel you can generate your SQL statements dynamically. You create a formula that has the sql in a string and concatenate the values dynamically. For example- [see here](http://chandoo.org/wp/2008/09/22/sql-insert-update-statements-from-csv-files/).

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention - Bulk insert is not an option due to the limitation on my work station.

Comment: so, in Excel you can generate your SQL statements dynamically. You create a formula that has the sql in a string and concatenate the values dynamically.

Comment: something like this: http://chandoo.org/wp/2008/09/22/sql-insert-update-statements-from-csv-files/

Comment: Can you change your answer that that is reflecting your comment then I can give you an up vote.

Comment: How does this not "repeat 600 * 3 INSERT statement. What are my options?"

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
INSERT INTO Membership (ID, FirstName, LastName, DOB)
VALUES (1, 'John', 'Smith', '5/5/1960'),
       (2, 'Hello', 'World', '4/9/1975')

INSERT INTO Account(ID, Type, Effective_Date, Status)
VALUES (1, 'Gold', GetDate(), 'Active'),
       (2, 'Platinum', GetDate(), 'Inactive')

INSERT INTO Participant(ID, Code, Type)
VALUES (1, 002, 'A'),
       (2, 002, 'A')
```

**Edit**

To avoid so much manual typing you can use following methods for specific DBMS

1. For mysql you can export file as .csv file and import using [this method](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)
2. For postgresql you can import .csv file run following

   ```
   >>psql mydatabase
   >>COPY mytable FROM '/myfile.csv' USING DELIMITERS ',';
   ```
3. For microsoft sql server (2000/2005) [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321686) knowledge base article would be useful. Another easy method can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3474137/3576835)
4. For oracle database [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/saternos-tables-090560.html) article is worth reading.

Comment: Thank you for trying, but like I mentioned in my comment, it only reduces the `VALUES` keyword, but it doesn't help me to reduce the need to enter the data 600 * 3 times

Comment: @C.J. You can export your excel file as `.csv` and depending on database you can import this file. for mysql see [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Comment: @C.J. For sql server you can use this KB article. (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321686)